# jQuery cambia valor de input text cuando arrastras el mouse arriba/abajo

Tags: jquery

Cómo puedo hacer que un Input de tipo Text cambie su valor cuando haga clic dentro de él y arrastre el mouse hacia arriba para aumentar el valor y hacia abajo para disminuir el valor. Sólo cuando el ratón se mueve hacia arriba y hacia abajo hace el cambio de valor de la entrada (validar min y max) Tengo esto, pero no puedo hacer que funcione como un deseo. miren el efecto que quiero hacer http://recordit.co/YJovptdj9f y esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/ggqzb27f/ pero necesito que funcione solo cuando el click de mouse este presionado osea como arrastrando de arriba o abajo asi como el ejemplo puesto

```
var clicking = false;
$('this').click(function() {
    clicking = false;
});
$('#change_value_up_down').mouseover(function() {
    clicking = true;
});
var i = 0;
var y = 0;
$(this).mousemove(function(my) {
    if (clicking === false) {
        return false;
    } else {
        // change value
        if (my.pageY <= $('#change_value_up_down').offset().top + $('#change_value_up_down').css('width').replace('px', '') / 10) {
            y = parseInt($('#change_value_up_down').val()) + 1;
            $('.movestatus').text('plus');
        } else {
            y = parseInt($('#change_value_up_down').val()) - 1;
            $('.movestatus').text('minus');
        }
        $('#change_value_up_down').val(parseInt(y));
        // Mouse click + moving logic here
        //$('.movestatus').text('mouse moved ' + i);
        i++;
    }
});
$('#change_value_up_down').mouseup(function(e) {
    clicking = false;
    //e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.selector').mouseup(function(e) {
    i = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en la 5ta linea reemplaza:

```
$('#change_value_up_down').mouseover(function () {
```

Por:

```
$('#change_value_up_down').mousedown(function () {
```

**Actualización:**

Bug en Google Chrome arreglado mediante el reemplazado de

línea 34:

```
$('#change_value_up_down').mouseup(function(e) {
```

Por:

```
$(this).mouseup(function(e) {
```

```js
 var clicking = false;
    $('this').click(function () {
                clicking = false;
            });
            $('#change_value_up_down').mousedown(function () {
                clicking = true;
            });
            var i = 0;
            var y = 0;
            $(this).mousemove(function(my){
                if(clicking === false) 
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // change value
                    if (my.pageY <= $('#change_value_up_down').offset().top + $('#change_value_up_down').css('width').replace('px', '')/10) 
                    {
                        y = parseInt($('#change_value_up_down').val()) +1 ;
                        $('.movestatus').text('plus');
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        y =  parseInt($('#change_value_up_down').val()) -1;
                        $('.movestatus').text('minus');
                        }
                    $('#change_value_up_down').val(parseInt(y));  
                    // Mouse click + moving logic here
                    //$('.movestatus').text('mouse moved ' + i);
                    i++;
                }
            });
            $(this).mouseup(function(e) {
                clicking = false;
                //e.stopPropagation();
            });
            $('.selector').mouseup(function(e) {
                i = 0;
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i>Only when the mouse moves up and down does
    the value change from the input
    (validate min y max)</i>
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<input type="text" value="5" id="change_value_up_down" />
  
  <!-- only ref -->
  <span class="clickstatus"></span>
  <span class="movestatus"></span>
```

Para mayor información sobre los eventos con el mouse en **jQuery** y aprender en sí la librería:

- https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/
- https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery
- https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery
- http://learn.jquery.com/
- http://www.desarrolloweb.com/manuales/manual-jquery.html

PD: si el idioma es una limitante, dale una patada espartana con algún traductor como Bing Translator, Google Translate, que traducen hasta del élfico :D y si inglés quieres aprender, aquí unas recomendaciones:

- https://www.memrise.com/
- https://www.duolingo.com/
- http://www.engvid.com/
- https://www.youtube.com/user/undostresingles

Comment: Hola! Estaría bien que ampliaras la respuesta con los cambios que has realizados ya que es complicado de saber que se ha hecho. Gracias! Un saludo.

Comment: complicado? bueno, ya que lo dices, vamos editando :D

Comment: Gracias @fredyfx, esta mejor, pero te lo comentaba porque los que andamos algo flojillos de js, nos viene bien que nos expliquen el porqué de los cambios, es decir,  porque en este caso funciona mousedown mejor que mouseover? Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: de nada hermano @IdirOuhabMeskine, estamos para servir, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de comentar, agrego unos enlaces de utilidad en breve :D

Comment: al hacer eso funciona pero si dejo de tener presionado el click igualmente funciona, lo que quiero es que solo incremente/decremente solo cuando el click este sostenido, para darle efecto de arrastre al usuario, y si dejo de tener el click sostenido deje de  incrementar/decrementar, necesito ayuda

Comment: interesante, lo que mencionas funciona en Google Chrome, sin embargo,  funciona perfectamente libre de errores en Firefox, MS Edge. Vamo a depurar :D

Comment: efectivamente, esto solo funciona en Firefox tal y cual como lo necesito, pero en chrome no funciona bien, como podras darte cuenta funciona diferente, te agradeceria si lo puedes hacer funcionar bien porque en firefox funciona perfecto.

Comment: listo hermano @iLen, respuesta editada :D

Comment: lo probe y funciona ya en chrome, pero si por ejemplo haces varias pruebas hacia arriba arrastrando y soltando el click unas 3 veces vuelve a incrementarse sin el click presionado, podrias revisar esta parte, por favor
pd: parece que solo tiene ese error cuando el arrastre es hacia arriba porque hacia abajo funciona perfecto no da ese problema en multiples intentos

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48621/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-ilen).